# Laravel 4 eloquent Mass assignment error in fillable

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm currently studying eloquent of `L4` and I encountered this mass assignment. I'd follow the instructions and I know you need to setup your `$fillable` to use the `create` method but I am still receiving a blank row in the database. here's my code:

MODEL:

```
class User extends Eloquent  
{
    protected $fillable = array('email','pwd','active','name');
}
```

CONTROLLER:

```
$user = new User;
$add = array(
    'name'=>Input::get('custname'),
    'active'=>1,
    'pwd'=>Hash::make(Input::get('pwd')),
    'email'=>Input::get('email')
);

return var_dump($user->create($add));
```

I also did:
CONTROLLER

```
$add = array(
'name'=>Input::get('custname'),
'active'=>1,
'pwd'=>Hash::make(Input::get('pwd')),
'email'=>Input::get('email')
);

return var_dump(User::create($add));
```

But still the same result.

Comment: Does it work when you just create the model with New User.  eg....  $user = New User; $user->name; etc etc $user->save()

Comment: Yes it works on that type of approach.

Comment: hmmm, so it is actually entering a new row into the database, but its just empty?  Are the created_at timestamps filled?

Comment: Yes. this is my error:   SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '' for key 'users_email_unique' (SQL: insert into `users` (`updated_at`, `created_at`) values (?, ?)) (Bindings: array ( 0 => '2013-06-08 07:38:07', 1 => '2013-06-08 07:38:07', ))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug causing this, see https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/1548
Should be fixed now, run `composer update` to get the newest version of `laravel/framework`

Answer (score 0):

Yes with new version you can use public or protected keywords.

Simple use this :

```
protected $fillable = [‘email’, ‘pwd’,’active’,’name’];
```

You can also specify table name if you are working with other Model like this :

```
public $table = ‘users’
```

This is working fine after run composer update on the root of project directory.